# Grails doesn't save domain's field

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes

```
class Country {
     ... // some fields, including other domains
}

class City {
     ... // some fields, including other domains
     Country itsCountry
}
```

One of my service method is here:

```
City createCity(String name, Country country) {
    // country is existing and loaded in the controller's layer and passed here
    City city = new City()
    city.itsCountry = country // it is not persisted
    city.save('flush':true)
}
```

The problem is that in the database the city has null country. 
Of course, I simplified the example, really is it more complicated. (Unfortunately, some important details can be lose, I hope if you faced this problem, you share the reason)

What I did without success:

1. playing with Country, getting it by id inside the service method, save and flush it before saving the City object
2. make the itsCountry field not nullable. So I got an exception from database, that this field can't be null.

I feel that it must be some trivial thing. What can be a reason of it?

Comment: Is your service `@Transactional`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't have such annotation,  but it must be transactional by default. (no "static transactional = false")

Comment: What version of Grails? Starting somewhere around Grails 3 services are non-transactional by default and that `static transactional` was removed.

Comment: Have you tried if(city.validate()){city.save(flush:true)}else{...} to see if the city object is validated? In the debugger you can then also access the validation errors of the city object.

Comment: what version of Grails and Gorm are u using?

Answer (score 0):

in Grails we can already get the country id in params .Right.
like for example, params?.countryId.

If it is new record for country table, then first create new object for country and assign in city object.

For example,

```
Country country = new Country()//for new record
country.name=params?.countryName
City city=new City()
city.itsCountry = country 
city.save('flush':true)
```

If you have already country record in table then use get method to get object and assign it to city.

For example,

```
Country country=Country.get(Long.valueOf(params?.countryId))
city.itsCountry = country 
city.save('flush':true)
```

I hope it will help you. If any doubt please ping me.